Cannot mound S3 bucket on Ubuntu system with s3fs
I'm trying to mound S3 butcket to my ubuntu 22 system.
This is my command:
s3fs bkt-storage:/storage /mnt/s3storage/ -o passwd_file=/etc/aws/.passwd-s3fs -d

My /etc/aws/.passwd-s3fs is formed like this:
PUBLICKEY:SECRETKEY

When i run this command with root user, I don't get any response, but looking into /var/log/syslog I find this errors:
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]: init v1.90(commit:unknown) with GnuTLS(gcrypt)
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]: check services.
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]:       check a bucket.
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]:       URL is https://s3.amazonaws.com/bkt-storage/
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]:       URL changed is https://bkt-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]:       computing signature [GET] [/] [] []
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]:       url is https://s3.amazonaws.com
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]: curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2357): HTTP response code 400, returning EIO. Body Text: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>#012<Error><Code>IllegalLocationConstraintException</Code><Message>The eu-south-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.</Message><RequestId>xxx</RequestId><HostId>xxx/xjDxPhA+fE3vsWkFrrBHPpIK6U=</HostId></Error>
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]: curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3421): Check bucket failed, S3 response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>#012<Error><Code>IllegalLocationConstraintException</Code><Message>The eu-south-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.</Message><RequestId>xxx</RequestId><HostId>xxx/xjDxPhA+fE3vsWkFrrBHPpIK6U=</HostId></Error>
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]: s3fs.cpp:s3fs_check_service(3575): Failed to connect by sigv4, so retry to connect by signature version 2.
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]: Pool full: destroy the oldest handler
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]:       check a bucket.
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]:       URL is https://s3.amazonaws.com/bkt-storage/
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]:       URL changed is https://bkt-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]: curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2357): HTTP response code 400, returning EIO. Body Text: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>#012<Error><Code>IllegalLocationConstraintException</Code><Message>The eu-south-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.</Message><RequestId>xxxx</RequestId><HostId>JgTscA21d1p/xxx=</HostId></Error>
May 24 12:21:53 srvap2 s3fs[3153]: curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3421): Check bucket failed, S3 response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>#012<Error><Code>IllegalLocationConstraintException</Code><Message>The eu-south-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.</Message><RequestId>xxxx</RequestId><HostId>JgTscA21d1p/xxx=</HostId></Error>

I tried to add -o url=https://s3.eu-south-1.amazonaws.com option, with no luck.
I tried to add -o endpoint=eu-south-1 option, with no luck.
Do you know how to solve?

The error message says "The eu-south-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to." so this is probably the wrong region.  Can you double-check it?
